# In Jolt, I have a list of objects as shown in example. Is there a way to extract an element and set a flag based on one of the field?

Tags: json, jolt

In this example, the "type" is unique and the list will not have more than one element with the same type.
The input list may or may not have the element with "type"= "B" and the expected output would vary based on that.

**Input when "type"= "B" exists:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "address": "123 ABC",
    "type": "A"
  },
  {
    "name": "Harry",
    "address": "456 DEF",
    "type": "B"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bonn",
    "address": "789 GHI",
    "type": "C"
  }
]
```

**Expected output if element with "type"= "B" exists:**

```
{
  "name": "Harry",
  "address": "456 DEF",
  "type": "B",
  "typeBFlag": true
}
```

**Expected output if element with "type"= "B" does not exist:**

```
{
  "typeBFlag": false
}
```

Looping through the input list and setting flag inside if condition would generate a flag as an array since we will be checking each element and setting the flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following transformation spec

```json
[
  { // label objects by types
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@1,type.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "B": { // add the desired attribute as default with value "false"
        "typeBFlag": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "B?": { // if the label "B" exists in the input JSON, then match otherwise skip
        "typeBFlag": true
      }
    }
  },
  { // filter out by type "B"(get rid of object label)
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "B": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Another alternative method would also be like this

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "type": {
          "B": { // whenever the type = "B" 
            "@2": "",
            "#true": "typeBFlag"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      // adds the following attribute if it doesn't exist
      "typeBFlag": false
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      // make it boolean value if it's of type string
      "*Flag": "=toBoolean"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you @Barbaros! Adding that default false was like an else condition.